# 4k display & Android emulator: fail

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-emulator

I'm moving to my new laptop which has 4k screen (3840x2160, to be exact). As my OS of choice I have Linux, and all scaling I have set up for this is done via Gnome (scaling-factor in gnome tweaks is set to 2). Overall, setup looks perfect, except for Android AVD run in IntelliJ IDEA.

AVD is configured to use skin with 1920x1080 dimensions, and I've expected that it would be roughly the height of the screen, however for some reason AVD is scaled up, which obviously looks.. weird and unusable.

I've took a look at relevant questions here about scaling the emulator, but it seems that IntelliJ interface has changed, as there is no `Emulator` tab in `Edit Configurations` menu (and answers to questions I've seen said to use that option to downscale the emulator). So, question is: how do I scale it down (or, to put more correctly, how do I disable the scaling for emulator)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found out what the issue was. UI scaling is handled by Qt in case of android emulator. It was set to: `QT_DEVICE_PIXEL_RATIO=2` somewhere in my configs. This made emulator act weird. Cheers!

Comment: Hi, do you mind share where did you change that parameter? I'm having the same issue. Cheers

Comment: @Buntupana in your profile, either /etc/profile, either ~/.profile, either in your environment settings for your DE.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the environment variable and restart Android Studio to get the new env variables.