# Emulator AVD does not scale display to 4k monitor

Tags: android, android-emulator, scaling, android-virtual-device

Since I upgraded my monitor to 4k, I have a problem with the Android emulator. On my system (KDE neon 5.15) the AVD does not scale the display of the device, but only the device itself, as it can be seen here: [Display of Android device not scaled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIVID.jpg). So it's almost impossible for me to click on the right area on the display, as the input field of the touch gestures is also scaled correctly, but only the display itself is not. I already checked similiar problems on stack overflow like [4k display & Android emulator: fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45396614/4k-display-android-emulator-fail), but non of them seem to have the same problem. Does any one else have experienced a similiar problem on Linux and 4k monitors?

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same problem with my Windows 10 computer. Here is a solution that works for me:

1. Switch your screen resolution to 1920 x 1080
2. Start the android emulator
3. While the emulator is running, switch your resolution back to 3840 x 2160 and it should be scaled properly

You will have to do this every time you start the emulator. 
Once you have it running properly in 4k DO NOT close the emulator because you will have to repeat the above steps.

This worked for me on my Windows 10 machine. I am not sure how it would respond on Linux.

Comment: This method worked on my Dell XPS 15 with a 4K pannel. It's still really annoying...

Comment: Yeah I think it is a problem with android studio